# XSS in AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss

We are using Angular JS in our app. I want to prevent all input fields from accepting JavaScript etc. Rather than check every single component is there a directive or something I could use out of the box which does this for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Rather than doing client side filtering, I would leave that to the server side component.
But client side will need to do the input validation stuff for the sake of user friendly.

Comment: That is what I mean by "But client side will need to do the input validation stuff for the sake of user friendly."

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer. -1 to @DaveMackintosh for giving an **awful** ignorant response.

Answer (score 5):

ngSanitize in angular 1.2.0 (and some earlier versions) can help you sanitize your inputs.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Or, alternatively, write your own filter that runs the input through regex to strip all HTML/JS/etc.

As a note, you should still have your server sanitize the inputs as well considering users can make direct requests against your server API and you may not have client side validation there.